# Obtain the equation problem

Tags: functions

If you have an amount of 1€, and you receive 100% interest at the end of the year, your amount will be 2€ after one year. If you instead receive 50% interest every half year, you will have $1.5^2=2.25€$. If you receive 25% interest every quarter, you will have $1.25^4=2.44€$.

What amount will you have if you receive the interest $n$ times per year?

Can someone explain me how he gets to the conclusion that
$(1+1/n)^n$ is the solution?

I understand that the first year the result will be: $1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$

I understand that the second year will be: $(1+\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2})$

It just doesn’t get into my head where the power enters:

I understand that factorizing the formula: $(1+\frac{1}{2})\cdot(1+\frac{1}{2})$

you’ll get somewhere but I don’t understand

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula for compound interest?

Comment: No, what is that?

Comment: See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Periodic_compounding).

Comment: Do today's students even remember times when interest rates were positive? ;)

Comment: I want to understand the logic of the power and of the compund interest, not the compound interest formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have your amount of $1€$ and you'll get $50\%$ interest two times a year, so after every 6 month. After the first half you will have $1€ \cdot 1.5 = 1.5€$, where we use the factor $1.5$ because you increase the amount of you money by $50\%$.
So far so good. Now after the second half of the year you'll get again $50\%$ interest on whatever you have in you bank account, in this case it's $1.5€$ from the first half. So we can do the calculation again: $1.5€ \cdot 1.5 = 2.25€$. Notice that we can rewrite this to

$$(\underbrace{\underbrace{(1€ \cdot 1.5)}_{\text{first half}} \cdot 1.5)}_{\text{second half}} = 1€ \cdot 1.5^2 = 2.25€$$

This can be applied to $n$ amounts per year, where your interest rate is $1/n$ and the factor to multiply your money is $1+1/n$:

$$(\underbrace{\dots(\underbrace{\underbrace{(1€ \cdot (1+1/n))}_{\text{first nth of the year}} \cdot (1+1/n)}_{\text{second nth of the year}}) \dots (1+1/n))}_{\text{last nth of the year}} = 1€ \cdot (1+1/n)^n$$

I hope this somewhat clarifies where the solution $(1+1/n)^n$ and the powers come from.

Fun Fact:
For $n \to \infty$ the factor will be Euler's number.
$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}(1+1/n)^n = e \approx 2.7182$$

Comment: WOW Thank you! I did not understand because I used 0.5 instead of 1.5! Very useful!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer and help me collect imaginary internet points ;)